# Encapsulating child classes

Tags: c++

I have a bunch of classes `Bar1`, `Bar2` etc. which all share a common parent class `Foo`. I want to hide them altogether and access them only via the interface provided by `Foo`'s virtual methods. I tried to nest them as private classes of `Foo` like that:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo ();
        static Foo *MakeBar (int someParams);

    private:
        class Bar1 : public Foo
        {
            Bar1 () : Foo () {}
        };

        class Bar2 : public Foo
        {
            Bar2 () : Foo () {}
        };

        // etc
};
```

However, this is not possible since class `Foo` is incomplete by the time class `Bar1` is being declared. Is there any other approach to prevent direct access to the child classes?

Comment: You'd typically just put them in an undocumented namespace named `detail`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do exactly what you wanted (making the Bar classes private to Foo) by splitting up the declaration of the classes:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo ();
    static Foo *MakeBar (int someParams);

private:
    class Bar1;
    class Bar2;

    // etc
};

class Foo::Bar1 : public Foo
{
    Bar1 () : Foo () {}
};

class Foo::Bar2 : public Foo
{
    Bar2 () : Foo () {}
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to move inherited classes from the class declaration to an unnamed namespace in implementation unit. Something like this:

### foo.h

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo ();
    static Foo *MakeBar (int someParams);
};
```

### foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

namespace {

class Bar1 : public Foo
{
      Bar1 () : Foo () {}
};

class Bar2 : public Foo
{
      Bar2 () : Foo () {}
};

} // endof unnamed namespace

Foo *Foo::MakeBar (int someParams)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Great, it works! Thank you. There is just one limitation to your solution: `Foo` itself cannot be a private nested class (but can be public nested).

Comment: In that case you have to declare Bar1 & Bar2 in Foo and define them outside

Comment: Yep, I think I like this even more.